# I don't have access to appDAtaFolder in Google Drive even if i have the right scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata) [403]

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I get **error 403 from Google** every time when I want to list files in appDataFolder.
I'm not sure if the service part is okay, but without it, uploading files etc doesn't work at all.
I'm new one here and also first time in my life using Google APIs.

Here goes the Error:

```
Google.GoogleApiException: „Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The granted scopes do not give access to all of the requested spaces. [403]
Errors [
    Message[The granted scopes do not give access to all of the requested spaces.] Location[spaces - parameter] Reason[insufficientScopes] Domain[global]
]
```

And here goes parts of my App code:

```
    const string appDataEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata";
     UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientID, ClientSecret = clientSecret },
                     scopes,
                     Environment.UserName,
                     CancellationToken.None,
                     new FileDataStore("MyAppsToken")).Result;

                var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "AppName"
                });
    ListFileGDrive(service);
     private static void ListFileGDrive(DriveService service)
            {
                var request = service.Files.List();
                request.Spaces = "appDataFolder";
                request.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
                request.PageSize = 10;
                var result = request.Execute();
                foreach (var file in result.Files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format(
                        "Found file: {0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id));
                }
            }
```

Comment: `credential` contains the variable `scopes`, but you variable containing the actual scopes is called `appDataEndpoint`?!